# Как зациклить функцию, используемую yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
def cube_numbers(nums):
    for i in nums:
        yield (i ** 3)
        if StopIteration:
           print("hello")


cubes = cube_numbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  
print(next(cubes),next(cubes),next(cubes),next(cubes),next(cubes),
next(cubes))
```

6-й вызов `next(cubes)` поднимает `StopIteration` ибо элементов у нас только 5.

Как сделать, чтобы вместо ошибки у меня итератор ставился на начало моей последовательности? То есть

```
>> (output): 1,8,27,64,125,1,8,27...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете применить функцию `cycle()` из модуля `itertools`; она из какого-нибудь итеровательного объекта сделает *бесконечный итератор* - и так не будет *никакого поднимания `StopIteration`*:

```
from itertools import cycle

def cube_numbers(nums):
    for i in cycle(nums):
        yield i ** 3
```

---

**Примечание.**

В вашем коде часть

```
    if StopIteration:
       print("hello")
```

бесполезна - это то же самое, как вы просто написали бы

```
    print("hello")
```

потому что `StopIteration` всегда вычисляется как `True` - см. в документации [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Вы наверно хотели вывести `hello` *только когда итератор исчерпывался*. Но:

1. Это *не делается* командой `if`, но как `try:... except StopIteration:`
2. Вы использовали итератор в сикле `for`, который *сам использует `StopIteration` для окончания цикла*, и так `StopIteration` для вас *никогда не поднимется*.

**Но вы можете для того применить в цикле ветвью `else`**, которая выполнится *только тогда*, когда цикл *нормально полностью завершится* (не встретится `break`) - в вашей исходной программе так:

```
from itertools import cycle

def cube_numbers(nums):
    for i in nums:
        yield (i ** 3)
    else:
        print("hello")
```

(в моем коде это не имеет смысла т.к. цикл бесконечен).

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import cycle

def cube_numbers(nums):
    for i in nums:
        yield (i ** 3)

cubes = cycle(cube_numbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
print(next(cubes),next(cubes),next(cubes),next(cubes),next(cubes),next(cubes))
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто вставите ваш цикл `for` в бесконечный цикл `while`:

```
def cube_numbers(nums):
    while True:
        for i in nums:
            yield i ** 3
```

Comment: Нарушается принцип единственной ответственности. И как минимум требует переименования в cube_numbers_infinity. Не лучший путь.